# difference between match and multimatch query type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I am bit confused over, elasticsearch match and multimatch query. What's the difference between both query types ? When each one of them must be used ? What's the performance implication of using each of them ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) is pretty clear that `multi_match` allows you to query across multiple fields while `match` uses a single field. Is there something else that is unclear?

Comment: I also want to know, performance implications of using multi_match instead of match in application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily see this differences between `multimatch` and `match` query difference with [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). For example, `multimatch` query with type `most_fields`

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "quick brown fox",
      "type":       "most_fields",
      "fields":     [ "title", "title.original", "title.shingles" ]
    }
  }
}
```

This would be executed as:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "title":          "quick brown fox" }},
        { "match": { "title.original": "quick brown fox" }},
        { "match": { "title.shingles": "quick brown fox" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `multimatch` query build from `match` queries. So, I think, the perfomance issue is related your query structure. You can choose another query wihch can be more productive or not.

The other type of the `multimatch` query is the same situation with `most_fields` type. For example, [`Phrase` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase), [`most_fields` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-most-fields).

Comment: Can you also elaborate on how best_field and cross_field will work for the example that you have given ? Thanks for most_field explaination.